# Datetime MYSQL issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query where I am trying to get all results from now() and also between now() and 10 minutes in the future.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND active = 1 
AND (
   date_added <= NOW() 
   OR 
   date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND NOW()
)
```

I am using the DATETIME column.

Could somewhere tell me where I am going wrong please.

Comment: If you subtract ten minutes from now, what do you get?

Comment: If something was added 1 second ago, it won't show up. Are you sure you don't want 10 minutes in the past?

Comment: Please show some sample data, what output you do get from this query, and what you wish to get.

Comment: Ah I had the BETWEEN part the wrong way round. Thanks

Comment: @Jay you want date_add

Comment: More coffee needed?

Comment: @Jay Please clarify the datetime you want to the records for,

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `DATE_ADD`:

```
select *
from table
where user_id = 1
    and active = 1
    and date_added between NOW() and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: @Forklift - Really?  In OP's code - `date_added <= NOW() OR`

Comment: @Forklift - I see. Updated then. I too need some coffee. :-)